# Links to forum keeps being truncated

Tags: laravel

Please I need help with how my links to the chatter forum are truncated when I click on discussions or any other link on the forum homepage.

A quick solution would be very much appreciated.[Kindly Check the URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EBuG.png)

Here's an example:

instead of;

localhost/apps/school/forums/discussions

it shows as:

localhost/forums/discussions

Below is the Route/web.php

```
 <?php

/**
 * Helpers.
 */

// Route helper.
$route = function ($accessor, $default = '') {
    return $this->app->config->get('chatter.routes.'.$accessor, $default);
};

// Middleware helper.
$middleware = function ($accessor, $default = []) {
    return $this->app->config->get('chatter.middleware.'.$accessor, $default);
};

// Authentication middleware helper.
$authMiddleware = function ($accessor) use ($middleware) {
    return array_unique(
        array_merge((array) $middleware($accessor), ['auth'])
    );
};

/*
 * Chatter routes.
 */
Route::group([
    'as'         => 'chatter.',
    'prefix'     => $route('home'),
    'middleware' => $middleware('global', 'web'),
    'namespace'  => 'DevDojo\Chatter\Controllers',
], function () use ($route, $middleware, $authMiddleware) {

    // Home view.
    Route::get('/', [
        'as'         => 'home',
        'uses'       => 'ChatterController@index',
        'middleware' => $middleware('home'),
    ]);

    // Single category view.
    Route::get($route('category').'/{slug}', [
        'as'         => 'category.show',
        'uses'       => 'ChatterController@index',
        'middleware' => $middleware('category.show'),
    ]);

    /*
     * Auth routes.
     */

    // Login view.
    Route::get('login', [
        'as'   => 'login',
        'uses' => 'ChatterController@login',
    ]);

    // Register view.
    Route::get('register', [
        'as'   => 'register',
        'uses' => 'ChatterController@register',
    ]);

    /*
     * Discussion routes.
     */
    Route::group([
        'as'     => 'discussion.',
        'prefix' => $route('discussion'),
    ], function () use ($middleware, $authMiddleware) {

        // All discussions view.
        Route::get('/', [
            'as'         => 'index',
            'uses'       => 'ChatterDiscussionController@index',
            'middleware' => $middleware('discussion.index'),
        ]);

        // Create discussion view.
        Route::get('create', [
            'as'         => 'create',
            'uses'       => 'ChatterDiscussionController@create',
            'middleware' => $authMiddleware('discussion.create'),
        ]);

        // Store discussion action.
        Route::post('/', [
            'as'         => 'store',
            'uses'       => 'ChatterDiscussionController@store',
            'middleware' => $authMiddleware('discussion.store'),
        ]);

        // Single discussion view.
        Route::get('{category}/{slug}', [
            'as'         => 'showInCategory',
            'uses'       => 'ChatterDiscussionController@show',
            'middleware' => $middleware('discussion.show'),
        ]);

        // Add user notification to discussion
        Route::post('{category}/{slug}/email', [
            'as'         => 'email',
            'uses'       => 'ChatterDiscussionController@toggleEmailNotification',
        ]);

        /*
         * Specific discussion routes.
         */
        Route::group([
            'prefix' => '{discussion}',
        ], function () use ($middleware, $authMiddleware) {

            // Single discussion view.
            Route::get('/', [
                'as'         => 'show',
                'uses'       => 'ChatterDiscussionController@show',
                'middleware' => $middleware('discussion.show'),
            ]);

            // Edit discussion view.
            Route::get('edit', [
                'as'         => 'edit',
                'uses'       => 'ChatterDiscussionController@edit',
                'middleware' => $authMiddleware('discussion.edit'),
            ]);

            // Update discussion action.
            Route::match(['PUT', 'PATCH'], '/', [
                'as'         => 'update',
                'uses'       => 'ChatterDiscussionController@update',
                'middleware' => $authMiddleware('discussion.update'),
            ]);

            // Destroy discussion action.
            Route::delete('/', [
                'as'         => 'destroy',
                'uses'       => 'ChatterDiscussionController@destroy',
                'middleware' => $authMiddleware('discussion.destroy'),
            ]);
        });
    });

    /*
     * Post routes.
     */
    Route::group([
        'as'     => 'posts.',
        'prefix' => $route('post', 'posts'),
    ], function () use ($middleware, $authMiddleware) {

        // All posts view.
        Route::get('/', [
            'as'         => 'index',
            'uses'       => 'ChatterPostController@index',
            'middleware' => $middleware('post.index'),
        ]);

        // Create post view.
        Route::get('create', [
            'as'         => 'create',
            'uses'       => 'ChatterPostController@create',
            'middleware' => $authMiddleware('post.create'),
        ]);

        // Store post action.
        Route::post('/', [
            'as'         => 'store',
            'uses'       => 'ChatterPostController@store',
            'middleware' => $authMiddleware('post.store'),
        ]);

        /*
         * Specific post routes.
         */
        Route::group([
            'prefix' => '{post}',
        ], function () use ($middleware, $authMiddleware) {

            // Single post view.
            Route::get('/', [
                'as'         => 'show',
                'uses'       => 'ChatterPostController@show',
                'middleware' => $middleware('post.show'),
            ]);

            // Edit post view.
            Route::get('edit', [
                'as'         => 'edit',
                'uses'       => 'ChatterPostController@edit',
                'middleware' => $authMiddleware('post.edit'),
            ]);

            // Update post action.
            Route::match(['PUT', 'PATCH'], '/', [
                'as'         => 'update',
                'uses'       => 'ChatterPostController@update',
                'middleware' => $authMiddleware('post.update'),
            ]);

            // Destroy post action.
            Route::delete('/', [
                'as'         => 'destroy',
                'uses'       => 'ChatterPostController@destroy',
                'middleware' => $authMiddleware('post.destroy'),
            ]);
        });
    });
});

/*
 * Atom routes
 */
Route::get($route('home').'.atom', [
    'as'         => 'chatter.atom',
    'uses'       => 'DevDojo\Chatter\Controllers\ChatterAtomController@index',
    'middleware' => $middleware('home'),
]);
```

Comment: if you want us to be able to help you might need to provide some details

Comment: Hello please I shared an image with the link kindly click on the image link

Comment: Without looking at the code its difficult to help. Can you provide the code where link is clicked from?

Comment: Looks like your testing with xampp. Either use `php artisan serve` to run your server to generate correct route url or change your default app_url config.

Comment: @Sandeesh would try that out

Comment: It's not being truncated, you need to set your base URL in `config/app.php` (the `'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost')` bit) and be sure to use the `url()` helpers instead of hard-coding URLs in your HTML. Or point your webserver at the Laravel install's `public` directory.

Comment: @Sandeesh it worked with localhost:8000 but when I changed the app_url config to the url I wanted, it didn't work I also changed it at env file too

Comment: @Micsedinam Yes it won't since the url rewriting won't happen. You need to stick with `php artisan serve` or set your  localhost root path to the application's `public` folder. This can get tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the root directory to point to the `public` folder in laravel for the url rewriting to work and this won't happen when you're using xampp/wamp and accessing the url like folder structure. Only the index page of laravel app would work and other pages would throw errors. Also the links generated would not be accurate since laravel uses the base app url.

You should run `php artisan serve` and access your app with `http://localhost:8000`. This solves your routing and url generating issues. The other option would be to modify the virtual hosts in your local installation which isn't as easy.